# CSS no-conflict styles

Tags: css

What's a good way to create a no-conflict version of a CSS stylesheet? Let's say you have a bunch of code with classes that overlap with Bootstrap's classes.

Is this valid: adding a `class="bootstrap"` to the ancestor element under which bootstrap styles should be applied, and then changing `bootstrap.css` to prefix every `rule {}` with `.bootstrap rule {}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason that would not work, but there are probably some performance implications to doing that - I'm not sure if they would even be significant enough to consider. It would probably be a better idea to rename the conflicting classes.

Here are a couple of resources to check out:

http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-selector-performance/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Writing_Efficient_CSS

And this is from Mozilla's CSS efficiency guidelines (2nd link): "This is the key to dramatically increasing performance. The fewer rules required to check for a given element, the faster style resolution will be."

Comment: You may also want to give Andy Edinborough's CSS Stress Tester a go: http://andy.edinborough.org/CSS-Stress-Testing-and-Performance-Profiling

Answer (score 2):

I've also needed to do this recently with the bootstrap form styles to avoid clashes, and I've found that you can surround all the @imports in the bootstrap.less (or your own custom version) with: `.bootstrap { ... }` and rebuild bootstrap. Now every CSS selector will be prefixed with `.bootstrap`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is an ugly approach and you will get into DOM Bashing (slower performance). Is there any reason why you couldn't just refactor your code and seperate the bootstrap styles entirely?

Comment: Let's pretend I can't change the conflicting 3rd-party CSS (hence the need for a no-conflict version).